# How to get plaintext of tx_news?

Tags: typo3, newsletter, tx-news, typo3-extensions

I'm trying to send a Newsletter with tx_news and direct_mail.
The HTML rendering is fine, but I have problems with the plain text and the documentation handles only tt_news.
How do I get the plaintext of tx_news?

Addendum: I only have a Template for the HTML rendering and a Template for the plaintext - the plaintext template is empty yet. I have integrated the template via TypoScript.

```
plugin.tx_directmail_pi1 {
    siteUrl = http://my.domain.com/
}

tx_directmail_pi1.10 = TEMPLATE
tx_directmail_pi1.10 {
template = FILE
template.file = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/Newsletter.tmpl
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some code.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution: Use a different template for plaintext. This is described in the manual at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Templates/Start/Index.html and afterwards use one of those scripts to transform HTML to plaintext. I found https://github.com/mtibben/html2text and https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text or search yourself for "plaintext html to text".

The reason is simple: there is no transformation available in news or the TYPO3 core which transforms the bodytext with its links to plain text.